# Rotating elements in a MATLAB multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, 3d, rotation

I have some form of cylindrical line source that I use to general a 3D kernal; I do this by generating a simple 2D kernal first, like so:

```
A = 625;
B =  25;

%2D kernal 
grid2d = zeros(101,101);
c = 51; %centre

for m = 1:101
    for n = 1:101

   r(m,n) = sqrt((m - c).^2 + (n - c).^2); %distance of point on grid to centre

   %Populating the grid as a kernal 

   if r(m,n) <= 5

       grid2d(m,n) = 100;

  elseif r(m,n) >= 25

      grid2d(m,n) = 0;

   else

      grid2d(m,n) = A./r(m,n) - B;

   end
    end
end
```

This gives me a 2D kernal. Now, if I define the 3D version as 9 elements long along the z axis inside a bigger grid, I can create the 3D kernel by the following;

```
gz = 147:155; %9 elements in the z axis
H = length(gz);
kernel3D = zeros(301,301,301); %

for n = 1:H

    kernel3D(151-50:1:151+50,151-50:1:151+50,gz(n)) = grid2d;
end
```

This works perfectly if I'm using vertical line sources, but I am curious whether it's possible to rotate the elements of this array in any desired direction so I might generate kernels for inclined sources; for example, let's say I wanted to rotate this array by 45 degrees relative to the XY plane and 60 degrees to the XZ plane through the centre of the line source at (151,151,151) ?

Is there an elegant way to do this, perhaps using rotation matrices?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a working, but inelegant, solution - in this version, I generated the 2D kernel, and nest it in a 3D array. Then I use rotation operaters to map the appropriate values at a position to the rotation transform. It's ugly, but appears to work.

```
  %generate a test 2d kernel as before...  

A = 625; B =  25; c = 51;  cen = 151; grid2d = zeros(101,101); 

for m = 1:101
for n = 1:101


        r(m,n) = sqrt((m - c).^2 + (n - c).^2 ); %distance of point on grid to centre

%Populating the grid as a kernal 

 if r(m,n) <= 5

    grid2d(m,n) = 100;

elseif r(m,n) >= 25

   grid2d(m,n) = 0;

 else

   grid2d(m,n) = A./r(m,n) - B;

  end
   end
  end

%make a bigger array for this to nest in
flat3d = zeros(301,301,301);
range = 101:201; %centre range of new grid

flat3d(range,range,cen) = grid2d;  % inserts grid2d at centre of new flat3d grid!  

%now the incline angles
theta = input('Enter incline in XZ (vertical) plane in degrees : ' );
phi = input('Enter incline in XY (horizontal) plane in degrees : ' );

%Now a loop which inclines each point relative to theta around (x,y,z) = (cen,cen,cen);

g = range(1); 

inc3d = zeros(301,301,301); %new inclined grid initialised 

for m = 1:101
for n = 1:101


   %the g - cen value is added to the index to map arrays sync up correctly and 
   %keep loop reasonable / avoid overlap outside index ! 

  xpart(m,n) = cen + cosd(theta).*(g + m -cen) - sind(theta).*(g + n - cen);  
  xn(m,n) = cen + cosd(phi).*(xpart(m,n) - cen) - sind(phi).*(g + n - cen); %this maps a value of x to new position theta and phi
  yn(m,n) = cen + sind(phi).*(xn(m,n) - cen) + cosd(phi).*(g + n - cen); %maps a value of y to new position relative to phi
  zn(m,n) = cen + sind(theta).*(g + m - cen) + cosd(theta).*(g + n - cen); %maps z to new position relative to theta (doesnt change relative to phi)

    xn = round(xn);
    yn = round(yn);  %round to avoid integer problems with indexing 
    zn = round(zn);


   inc3d(xn(m,n),yn(m,n),zn(m,n)) = flat3d(g + m,g + n,cen);

 end
end
```

This appears to work; if I generate a plot3 picture of theta = 30 and phi = 15, for example, I get something like this;

[image]

From this 2D flat image, with the equation of the line, I think one could simply sum up and generate the kernel for which ever regions are required. This is messy, but seems to work. If anyone knows a cleaner way, by all means add it :)